# Difference between Bootstrap DataTables' paging vs pagination

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I want to remove the pagination of Bootstrap DataTables. According to answers found in the internet, I have to make 3 modifications as,

```
$('#table_id').dataTable({    
    "bInfo": false, //Dont display info e.g. "Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries"
    "paging": false,//Dont want paging                
    "bPaginate": false,//Dont want paging      
})
```

I have tried this with disabling various combinations of the 3 parameters and both the options **paging** and **bPaginate** seem to be giving the same result when set to false.

So what is the difference between above two options?

Comment: They are the same: `bPaginate` is the 1.9.x and below hungarian notation naming, `paging` is the 1.10.x and forth camelCase naming, `bPaginate` still works for convenience / easier upgrade; the old attribute names is by the way still in use internally (new features is not named that way)

Comment: [bPaginate](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features#bPaginate) is part of legacy datatable while [paging](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging) is part of latest version of datatable.

Comment: @davidkonrad, that should be an answer, not a comment! :) +1

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, the alternative is a big fat **RTFM**  :) I see no value for stackoverflow pointing out truisms. Should we have SO entrances for "*what is the difference between mRender and render*?", "*what is the difference between sClass and className?*" and so on also ..? If anyone will answer I will not complain, there exists no particular duplicates, if there is a low rep user reading this - go ahead and answer!